# Sorting list to match its ordering to a string

Tags: python, string, list, sorting, python-3.x

One of my functions outputs/returns a list of strings, for example

```
["on", "p", "h", "yt"]
```

How can I sort the list so that it matches the order of the characters in the string `"python"`? The desired result is

`["p", "yt", "h", "on"]`

Comment: How did you come up with that and what exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? post the function to which you are giving your input and give some sample inputs and outputs.

Comment: how did you get the list_output values? or you are simply assigning it..?

Comment: Clarified the question, voted to reopen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I understand your question you can sort by index.

```
>>> mystring = "python"
>>> list_output = ["on", "p", "h", "yt"]
>>> sorted(list_output, key=mystring.index)
['p', 'yt', 'h', 'on']
```